# How does an ASP.NET Core app build?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The app type is `Console Application` and it has a `Program` class with a `Main` entry point, yet I can find no trace of any `.exe` build output. Where could I look for such an `.exe`, or does VS's build profile dictate it's deletion after building and converting into a dll or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As .NET Core application can be run in multiple platforms and there is no `.exe`. The tool responsible for running the application is `dotnet run` command and it hosts your dll.

A quote from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/)

> The 'dotnet' app host, which is used to launch .NET Core apps. It
>   selects the runtime and hosts the runtime, provides an assembly
>   loading policy and launches the app. The same host is also used to
>   launch SDK tools in much the same way.

Comment: Then surely the app type should be `Class Library`, like all other, standard .NET web apps that are hosted in another process.

Comment: A class library wouldn't have an entry point. Even though the assembly ends up as a DLL the runtime still needs to know where/how to start your application up.

Comment: @Polynomial Surely an ASP.Core app could provide an interface for the entry point? Then `dotnet.exe` sees it as a web app and calls that entry point.

Comment: I have since found out why the app must be structured as an executable. When used e.g. with IIS, the web server will start that executable instead of a worker process. Something like that. Details found in "Debugging ASP.NET Core Under IIS".